# Receber conteúdo da tabela pelo WebBrowser?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela.

```
<table class="table1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>SEQ</th>
                    <th>LOGIN</th>
                    <th>WHATSAPP</th>
                    <th>E-MAIL</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">name</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">99 999999999</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">xxxxxxx@hotmail.com</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Gostaria de saber como obter conteúdo de cada TR para gravar no Access Database.

Porque até o momento eu só consegui chegar a este código.

```
Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement
            If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "table1") Then
                TextBox1.Text = CurElement.InnerHtml

            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Tenta usar `class` em vez de `className`.

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway Ele tá retornando certinho, minha dúvida é como separar e pegar somente os dados dentro dos TD, exemplo, como pego os e-mails. pois são vários.

Comment: *Yeah! The penny finally dropped!*